# Can you use a WatchViewStub in a GridViewPager for Android Wear?

Tags: android, wear-os

I have a WatchViewStub that works fine on its own - it displays the correct layout on the appropriate square or round android wear emulator.  But when I try and use the WatchViewStub in a GridViewPager it always displays the square (or rectangle) layout even on the round emulator.  Is it possible to use the two together successfully?

Here are some code fragments:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_wear);

    GridViewPager pager = (GridViewPager) findViewById(R.id.activity_wear_pager);
    pager.setAdapter(new gridViewPagerAdapter());

    DotsPageIndicator dotsPageIndicator = (DotsPageIndicator) findViewById(R.id.activity_wear_page_indicator);
    dotsPageIndicator.setPager(pager);
}
```

Here's the gridViewPagerAdapter:

```
private class gridViewPagerAdapter extends GridPagerAdapter {
    @Override
    public int getColumnCount(int arg0) { return 2; }

    @Override
    public int getRowCount() { return 1; }

    @Override
    protected Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int row, int col) {
        View view = null;

        if (col == 0) {
            view = LayoutInflater.from(getApplicationContext()).inflate(R.layout.read_page_stub, container, false);
            WatchViewStub stub = (WatchViewStub) view.findViewById(R.id.read_page_stub);
            stub.setOnLayoutInflatedListener(new WatchViewStub.OnLayoutInflatedListener() {
                @Override
                public void onLayoutInflated(WatchViewStub stub) {
                }
            });
        }
        else {
            view = LayoutInflater.from(getApplicationContext()).inflate(R.layout.find_page_stub, container, false);
            WatchViewStub stub = (WatchViewStub) view.findViewById(R.id.find_page_stub);
            stub.setOnLayoutInflatedListener(new WatchViewStub.OnLayoutInflatedListener() {
                @Override
                public void onLayoutInflated(WatchViewStub stub) {
                }
            });
        }

        container.addView(view);
        return view;
    }

    @Override
    protected void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int row, int col, Object view) {
        container.removeView((View)view);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
        return view==object;
    }
}
```

Here is activity_wear.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <android.support.wearable.view.GridViewPager
        android:id="@+id/activity_wear_pager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:keepScreenOn="true"/>

    <android.support.wearable.view.DotsPageIndicator
        android:id="@+id/activity_wear_page_indicator"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|bottom">
    </android.support.wearable.view.DotsPageIndicator>

</FrameLayout>
```

Here is read_page_stub.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.wearable.view.WatchViewStub
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/read_page_stub"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:rectLayout="@layout/read_page_rect"
    app:roundLayout="@layout/read_page_round"
    tools:context=".WearApplication"
    tools:deviceIds="wear">
</android.support.wearable.view.WatchViewStub>
```

Then I have two layouts with my views.  They start with:

read_page_rect.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/scroll"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".WearApplication"
    tools:deviceIds="wear_square">
```

read_page_round.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/scroll"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".WearApplication"
    tools:deviceIds="wear_round">
```

I have the same type of layout setup for find_page_stub, find_page_rect, and find_page_round.

Comment: Another approach would be to use a FragmentGridPagerAdapter (which extends GridPagerAdapter) and populate fragments in getFragment(...) in the fashion of SomeFragment.newInstance(listOfObjects.get(row));

Then inside SomeFragment's onCreateView you do the WatchViewStub stuff.

That works well for me and I have not had any need for dealing with WindowInsets.

Answer (score 2):

If `WatchViewStub` doesn't show the round layout it means it doesn't receive the `WindowInsets` object properly. `GridViewPager` must be consuming it somewhere on the way.

You can try and fix it. The way to do this is (first some theory):

1) start by reading about [`View.dispatchApplyWindowInsets`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#dispatchApplyWindowInsets(android.view.WindowInsets)) and [`View.onApplyWindowInsets`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#onApplyWindowInsets(android.view.WindowInsets))

2) the way these two methods are tied in a `View` is this: `dispatchApplyWindowInsets` is called and checks if there is any listener; if yes, it delivers the `WindowInsets` to the **listener** only; if no, it delivers the `WindowInsets` to `onApplyWindowInsets`.

3) in a `ViewGroup` (and `GridViewPager` is a `ViewGroup`) it iterates over the children and checks if the insets were consumed; if yes, it stops delivering them;

4) at any point any `View`/`ViewGroup` can decide to stop delivering the `WindowInsets`; when it does, any children depending on it won't behave properly on round;

now some practice:

5) you can create a subclass of any view you have in your hierarchy; do this with `GridViewPager` and start experimenting with overriding `dispatchApplyWindowInsets` and `onApplyWindowInsets`. My guess is the first one should be enough.

6) in the override of `dispatchApplyWindowInsets` iterate over children and call `dispatchApplyWindowInsets` to every of them; this way `WatchViewStub` should receive unaltered `WindowInsets` with the previous `isRound()->true` method

7) finally, don't forget to call `super.dispatchApplyWindowInsets(windowInsets)`; you want to let `GridViewPager` do what it needs with the insets.

Phew, pretty long, but should help you and also give you some understanding why things are happening the way are happening. I think we have a bug standing to fix this `GridViewPager` issue, so maybe after the next release you won't have to deal with this.

Comment: Thanks for the info, this is helpful although I'm struggling to implement your subclass idea - I ran into a class cast exception that I'm not sure how to resolve. At any rate, this sounds like a bug in Android Wear so maybe my best course of action at this point is to give up on the WatchViewStub approach and make my layouts the same for rect/round or find a way to determine the shape dynamically.

Comment: What is the exception you are seeing? Can you update your question?

Answer (score 0):

As [@gruszczy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/98494/gruszczy) mentions, the GridViewPager consumes the WindowsInsets callbacks by default. The way to fix this is to manually set it to not do it by code:

```
mGridViewPager.setConsumeWindowInsets(false);
```

This method set an internal boolean attribute that is used on the dispatcher method of the insets. As can be seen here:

```
 public WindowInsets dispatchApplyWindowInsets(WindowInsets insets) {
    insets = this.onApplyWindowInsets(insets);
    if(this.mOnApplyWindowInsetsListener != null) {
        this.mOnApplyWindowInsetsListener.onApplyWindowInsets(this, insets);
    }

    return this.mConsumeInsets?insets.consumeSystemWindowInsets():insets;
}
```

As a final note, this is on version 1.3.0 of the Support Wearable library. I'm not sure if this is included on previous versions...