# Android wear app displaying rect layout on round watch

Tags: android, wear-os

I've got an Android wear app but when I run it on a round watch (Moto 360) instead of the round layout being displayed the rectangular one is.

When a new wear project is created, Android Studio creates all the necessary layout files to enable it to automatically load the rectangular layout our circular layout as appropriate and I haven't altered this except for the content  of the rectangular or round layout files themselves. In particular *I have not altered the activity_main.xml nor the names of the rect or round activities nor how the loading takes place within the activity*.

Here is activity_main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.wearable.view.WatchViewStub
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/watch_view_stub"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:rectLayout="@layout/rect_activity_main"
    app:roundLayout="@layout/round_activity_main"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    tools:deviceIds="wear"></android.support.wearable.view.WatchViewStub>
```

Here's the start of round_activity_main.xml, there's no point in showing it all:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" tools:context=".MainActivity" tools:deviceIds="wear_round">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
```

For completeness here is the start of the rect_activity_main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" tools:deviceIds="wear_square"
    android:clickable="true">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
```

And here is how the layout is loaded in the activity's onCreate()

```
   setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
            WatchViewStub stub = (WatchViewStub) findViewById(R.id.watch_view_stub);
            stub.setOnLayoutInflatedListener(new WatchViewStub.OnLayoutInflatedListener()
            {
                @Override
                public void onLayoutInflated(WatchViewStub stub)
                {
                ...
```

Everything is as its supposed to be as far as I can tell, and like I mentioned it should be as I haven't changed what Android Studio created.
Anybody any idea what the issue could be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start by checking out this answer, I explain how the `WindowInsets` are delivered: [Can you use a WatchViewStub in a GridViewPager for Android Wear?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28975375/can-you-use-a-watchviewstub-in-a-gridviewpager-for-android-wear/28978713#28978713)

After that:

1. Are you using this inside of an Activity?
2. Do you have some OnApplyWindowInsetsListener set?
3. Try calling stub.requestApplyInsets() in onCreate.

EDIT:

From the discussion in the comments and further investigation. It seems that you need to set `<item name="windowOverscan">true</item>` on your theme for `WindowInsets` to be dispatched to your views.

Comment: Thanks I'll read and digest your answer in the other posting soon, but in the meanwhile yes this is being used within an activity. My app is very small and simple - there's just the WearableListenerService that creates the only activity, there's no OnApplyWindowInsetsListener being set.

Comment: Could you upload your code to github for inspection?

Comment: I've not uploaded the project files but here are all the java and layout and manifest files for the app https://github.com/mungbeans2/AndroidWearRoundProblem

Comment: I'm looking at your code and I have absolutely no idea why it's not being round. Could you run `adb logcat | grep WatchViewStub` when starting your activity?

Comment: There's nothing in logcat for WatchViewStub

Comment: I'm afraid out of ideas :-(

Comment: Thanks anyway. I think I'll start with a clean Android Studio template project that displays on square and round, then bit by bit add my stuff and see if it continues to work or breaks at some point.

Comment: I found out what it was - if the type of the activity is changed from Theme.DeviceDefault to Theme.Translucent then the square layout is always loaded instead of the round. Its not just my activity, if a new wearable project is created with Android Studio and then the *only* thing that is changed is the theme, then the square layout gets loaded. Is this a bug?

Comment: I am afraid it might be a bug.. I will report to the right engineer.

Comment: Actually, it might not be a bug. I checked the code and edited my answer. You should be able to continue to use Theme.Translucent, but you will need to inherit it and a new value.

Comment: Great, it works. Thanks a lot, I would never have got that solution without your help. I can't even find mention of the use of windowOverscan on the internet. Is this behavior actually a bug but using windowOverscan is a workaround?

Comment: Hmmm, if I use adb screencap to take a screenshot then the results are square and not circular. Any idea why that is? I was expecting a circular image like here http://www.androidcentral.com/how-take-screenshot-your-android-wear-device

Comment: I am not sure, I think it's an intended behavior to only deliver insets to windows with overscan.

Comment: I always use `adb shell screencap -p | perl -pe 's/\x0D\x0A/\x0A/g' > screen.png` screenshots and it usually works out for me fine.

Comment: I wrote a blog post about detecting WindowInsets here: http://gruszczy.blogspot.com/2015/03/handling-round-screens-using.html

Answer (score 1):

If you want a simple solution without hard way of `WindowInsets` you should take a look at this library: https://github.com/tajchert/ShapeWear 
Just call `ShapeWear.initShapeWear(this);` once to initialize and this is it - just call `getShape()` at any time.